# How to query whether a field exists in the collection using _id in mongodb using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a collection `twitter` which contains documents having `email` as `_id` and `token` field as `string`.

```
{
    "_id":"abc@gmail.com",
    "token":"TWTR",
    "screen_name":"xyz",
    "location":"pqr"
}
{
    "_id":"jkl@gmail.com",
    "screen_name":"jkl",
    "location":"abc"
}
```

how to write a query in java which returns `true` only if `token` value exist in all other cases return `false` whether `token` value is null or `empty`. For example in the above twitter collection it should return `true` for `"_id":"abc@gmail.com"` and `false` for `"_id":"jkl@gmail.com"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `$ne` and "$exists" operators and `count()` method in these matters:

```
private static boolean exist(DBCollection coll, String key)
{
    DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("token", new BasicDBObject( "$ne", "").append("$exists", true)).append("_id", key);

    return coll.count(query) == 1;      
}

exist(coll, "abc@gmail.com"); // true
exist(coll, "jkl@gmail.com"); // false
```

Comment: wow, It worked perfectly. Awesome mentors are on stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

For checking both `null` and `empty` values you can also use [$nin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator.For example

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("token", new BasicDBObject("$nin", Arrays.asList("",null)));
```

**$nin selects the documents where:**

```
- the field value is not in the specified array or
- the field does not exist.
```